Los snippets y shortcuts con '^' y '_' no funcionan en vscode
Trabajo en LaTex desde vscode, y quisiera que, así como se cierran los paréntesis y llaves automáticamente, al presionar en '^' en un archivo .tex aparezca '^{}' con el cursor entre las llaves. No tengo pleno conocimiento de cómo hacerlo, pero con snippets y shortcuts no de deja por alguna razón. Debo aclarar que trabajo desde debian, y por ende el primer '^' que hago está condicionado por la siguiente tecla, esto es, no es un caracter por sí mismo a menos que lo ejecute 2 veces. Ejemplo: primero '^', luego 'a' = â. Pero esto no sucede con '_'. Agradecería su ayuda, me facilitaría la escritura en el día a día.
Como mencioné anteriormente, intenté con snippets y shortcuts:
snippets:
"Insert ^{}": {
     "prefix": "^",
     "body": "^{}",
     "description": "Insert ^{}"
}

shortcuts:
{
    "key": "^",
    "command": "type",
    "args": {"text": "^{}"},
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'latex'"
}

Tengo la sospecha que vscode no recibe
